# Cannot start Steam.exe from Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..)

Tags: java, exec

I have been trying to start Steam from inside my Java program.

I have tried this:

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
Process p;
try {
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe start \"\" \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe\" -login myid mypassword"); //the string amounts to start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe" -login myid mypassword
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
    output.append(line + "\n");
}
System.out.println(output);
```

This would do nothing. I don't even get any error. My mouse becomes a **loading mouse** as if something is loading in the background. But actually nothing happens.

Although, when I try to run commands such as `taskkill /F /IM Steam.exe`, they work perfectly fine and actually I see Steam closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run it by removing `start`.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe\" -login myid mypassword");
```

Even removing cmd.exe worked as well

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe\" -login myid mypassword");
```

But I ran into a very little problem, which I will ask some other time. That little problem is that the process won't execute the next instruction unless I close the Steam. I tried to run it with cmd.exe /c flag, but that didn't work either.